# Converting a Text(tab delimited) to PHP associative array, instead of this code for CSV?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I would like to convert my CSV to Array code to a Text(tab delimited) to Array block of code. Here is my existing that works for comma's...

```
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', $content);
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
print_r($csv);
```

What would be the shortest way to convert for example the 'str_getcsv' to accept tabs over commas as default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', $content, array_fill(0, count($content), "\t"));
```

Comment: Instead of `array("\t")` there should be something like `array_fill(0, count($content), "\t")`

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: what would that do?

Comment: the second argument for `str_getcsv` should be applied for every item in `$content`, so parameters array should be same size as `$content`. Now it only works for first element and throws notices for others.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: str_getcsv `"Parses a string input for fields in CSV format and returns an array containing the fields read"`. The second argument `\t` will ask str_getcsv to replace comma with tab as the separator.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller and Raidenace. The array_fill(0, count($content), "\t") worked, while the other did throw errors.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: I stand corrected. You should post the answer and give an explanation

Comment: @Raidenace I was going to post my proposition with lambda function but I liked your answer better, so credits should go to you.

Answer (score 1):

This puts it in a string with tab delimiters. Then you can either explode it to an array or use it as is.

```
$csv = implode("\t", str_getcsv($file, ","));
```

Comment: BTW, str_replace is the fastest way to do it with code. preg_replace with a regular expression is the next best/fastest way.

Comment: I am looking at saving the file as a text without use of comma at all to allow comma in data if needed.

Comment: So in that case you could use fwrite with the $csv string I wrote up there and it would do exactly what you're asking for. `fwrite($handle, $csv);` and more info is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)